# Initializing functions important?

Tags: function, delphi, initialization

My teacher said that initializing a function is important. I know why you would initialize a variable, but don't understand why you'd do that with a function.

```
function f(n: integer):integer;
begin
    f := 0; //what my teacher wants me to do
    Result := n + 1;
end;
```

Comment: Are you *sure* that's what he meant? Because that dosen't make much sense, and your example won't compile.

Comment: I suggest you ask your teacher for a complete example that actually compiles. Either you've misunderstood, in which case you'll learn something, or the teacher will see that *they've* misunderstood.

Comment: This question makes sense in Delphi, but it does not for C# or some other languages. This is very language specific behavior. Each language has it's own rules. Don't add irrelevant language tags to your questions because it will get closed by people not understanding relevance of the question in wrong language.

Comment: As for why do you have to initialize function result in Delphi - because if you don't initialize result it will have undefined value. In your specific example initializing is not important because there is only single execution path that sets value with `f := n + 1;` In more complex functions you can have more execution paths and you have to make sure that each single one sets the function result. Sometimes it is simpler and safer to initialize function result up front to some default value.

Comment: That is what your teacher is trying to teach you. Initialization is not necessary if you are sure that result will always be set at some point, but it is safe way of making sure that your function result will always be initialized in Delphi.

Comment: If your teacher really said that then you need to find a better teacher. Clearly it is pointless to assign to the same variable twice. Replace `f := 0; f:= n + 1;` with `f := n + 1;` and, FWIW, assigning to `Result` is idiomatic for Delphi.

Comment: Assigning a function result is sometimes a trick in JIT-tracing languages (e.g. [V8 and JavaScript](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/v8/)) to define an explicit type of a (return) variable, to enhance performance. But in Delphi, it is a non-sense, and the compiler will complain about the `f := 0` assignment, and would perhaps even not compile the line into the exe!

Comment: BTW originally the question was tagged `c#` only; in 3rd revision somebody added `delphi` tag, evidently to make the question meaningful; next editors removed `c#` tag and edited the function's code to make it compilable in Delphi.

Now, can you tell what has been asked here?

Comment: Agreed with @user246408 - somehow this got transformed into a `delphi` question with no clear reason as to why.

Comment: Assume i'm your teacher. Hey kid, remember this well, **initializing a function is extremely important**.... if : (1) You have `exit;` code in your function. (2) There are so many nested condition (`if` or `case`) in your function that make you not sure wether the function returns any value. (3) Your function contains too many lines that make you not sure where is the start and where is the end. But the most important thing is **Please don't pay attention on bold statement only**. The statement after that is the most crucial part.

Comment: @J... this question was retagged as Delphi because OP added Delphi code in comments and later on he edited it with Delphi code. I reverted the question to his latest revision because it is creal that this was the question he wanted to ask.

Comment: What's going on here? Can the **OP** please confirm if this is a `Delphi` or `c#` question?

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar - I see.  The edit history was confusing.  One third-party edited the tags to `delphi`, then someone else edited the code to be delphi code.  Neither of these people were OP so it seemed highly bizarre that op would have tagged c# originally if that wasn't what they were talking about.  Useful if people leave comments in the edit history in a case like this...

Comment: @kobik it is Delphi question but OP was confused by the teacher that said that all languages behave the same. He didn't have exact Delphi code when he asked the question so he made mish-mash C# code that didn't compile, later on he added real Delphi code in comments and someone edited the question to reflect that. At that time question was closed, I voted to open and at that time added answer for his Delphi code in comments. Unfortunately, some of the comments that explain all this mess (including OP's with Delphi code) were deleted.

Comment: Revision history of this question is great example of **good faith vandalism**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Delphi function `Result` is undefined unless you set specific value to it. So you always have to initialize/set function `Result` at some point in your function.

In your specific example initializing is not important because there is only single execution path that sets value with `f := n + 1;`

Also Delphi compiler can recognize that value assigned in first line is never used and show you warning message (depending on version and warning settings): `H2077: Value assigned to ‘Result’ never used`

```
function f(n: integer):integer;
begin
    Result := 0; // not important because it will be set with next line
    Result := n + 1;
end;
```

In more complex functions you can have more execution paths and you have to make sure that each single one sets the function result. Sometimes it is simpler and safer to initialize function result up front to some default value.

```
function f(n: integer):integer;
begin
    Result := 0; // this is important because if n <= 0 Result will be undefined
    if n > 0 then Result := n + 1;
end;
```

Of course, you can write above as

```
function f(n: integer):integer;
begin
    if n > 0 then Result := n + 1
    else Result := 0;
end;
```

Upfront initialization is not necessary. However, it is necessary that function result is set for each possible execution path in your function.

Also, using function name to set function value is obsolete technique. Using `Result` is preferable.

One important note. Different languages have different rules about returning/seting function results. There is no “one rules them all”. Keep in mind that this is very language specific question.

Comment: You have turned this question from C# to delphi without a clear reason. The OP did not mention delphi at any point, and the code example was C#.

Comment: @jeroenh I didn't do that OP did that if you would look at question revision history. Last OP edit of the question was about Delphi.

Comment: @jeroenh question was reopened because it made sense for Delphi, and it was closed because first version of code would not even compile in C#. But someone deleted all comments that flashed that fact to the surface.

Comment: Confusing, to say the least.